# Aproximação de casa decimal em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Qual o motivo do comportamento abaixo? Porque não dá 3.3?

Estou executando no console o JavaScript e está retornando esse resultado.

```
Number(1.1)
1.1

Number(1.1) + Number(1.1)
2.2

Number(1.1) + Number(1.1) + Number(1.1)
3.3000000000000003

Number(1.1) + Number(1.1) + Number(1.1) + Number(1.1)
4.4

Number(1.1) + Number(1.1) + Number(1.1) + Number(1.1) + Number(1.1)
5.5
```

Comment: Qual comportamento?

Comment: O 3.3000000000000003 ao invés de 3,3... @MiguelNeto

Answer (score 3):

Isto acontece devido a erros de precisão da vírgula flutuante, uma vez que não é possível mapear 1.1 para um valor binário finito. Uma questão semelhante pode ser vista [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript).
Este comportamento pode ser alterado através da função toFixed().
Exemplo:

```
(1.1 + 1.1 + 1.1).toFixed(2)
```

Sendo 2 o número de casas decimais.

Answer (score 2):

Number é uma função javascript que Converte a string num valor ponto flutuante
Veja que dentro do parenteses tem .(ponto), então a string dentro do parenteses é convertida para ponto flutuante.